# Are there any common functions having order of magnitude between $x$ and $\log x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, logarithms

Since $x\gg \log x$ as $x$ tending to infinity. I wonder if there is some function $f(x)$ not of form $x^\delta$ or $(\log x)^k$ such that $x\gg f\gg \log x$?

Comment: Define "common"?

Comment: The prime counting function, $\pi(x) \sim \operatorname{Li}(x)$.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, you are right. It's hard to define it. So I deleted.

Comment: With your new question... the answer is "of course, infinitely many." Weighted geometric sums of $x$ and $\log x$, things involving $\log\log x$, or $\log^{(k)} x$ ($\log$ iterated $k$ times), or many more exotic things...

Answer (score 1):

Sure: for instance, $\sqrt{x\log x}$.

Comment: Mh, are *common* and *ad-hoc* synonyms ?

Answer (score 1):

Among the elementary functions (polynomials, rational fractions, exponentials, trigonometric and their inverses), none has this behavior.

You can create as many as you want by interpolating between $x$ and $\log x$, but this is of little interest.

Comment: "...not of the form $x^\delta$ or $(\log x)^k$..."

Comment: @Wojowu: you are right. Discarding. Please also be critical about the *common* requirement. Until now, only Daniel Fischer gave a correct contribution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The OP is not requiring that anymore.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: still in the title, and that doesn't invalidate my other comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about:
$$
(\log x)^{\log\log x} =e^{({\log\log x})^2}
$$

Since: $$(\log x)^k=e^{k\log\log x} \ll e^{({\log\log x})^2} \ll e^{\delta\log x}=x^\delta$$

for any positive $k$ and $\delta$.